# Давно не чищенный или давно нечищеный

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Прошу дать ответ: как пишутся данные словосочетания:

> *давно **не чищенный***
>
> или
>
> *давно **нечищеный***

Я считаю, что верным является первый вариант, так как перед нами причастие с зависимым словом. Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Всё верно, причастие от глагола несов. вида  с зависимым словом - -НН-

Answer (score 0):

Правильно раздельное написание, это да.
Но вот с мотивировкой дело обстоит чуть сложнее.

Вообще говоря наречие при причастии может и не являться тем самым зависимым словом, на основании наличия которого делается однозначный вывод о раздельном написании. Надо в таких случаях смотреть глубже.

В данном случае слитное написание просто не проходит по смыслу. Если предположить что "нечищеный" это категория качества (требующая поэтому слитного написания), то к ней невозможно применить слово "давно". Таким образом в данном случае "давно" действительно становится зависимым словом.

Answer (score 0):

**Давно не чищенный**, раздельное написание причастия при наличии зависимого слова, две буквы  НН в причастии.

Наличие зависимых слов ― **формальное правило**, поэтому обычно нет необходимости анализировать их семантику. Зависимые слов обычно **переходят** к причастию  из глагольного сочетания: ** давно не чистить ― давно не чищенный.**

В очень редких случаях отглагольное прилагательное может иметь собственные зависимые слова, например: **явно крашеные** (ненатуральные) волосы.